# Is it possible to manage a github wiki (perhaps with gollum) without a local working directory?

Tags: github, gollum-wiki

I'd like to build a (ruby) script that interacts with a github wiki.

[Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum#readme) seems to want to manage a local working directory.

Is it possible to interact directly with a github wiki?

Answer (score 0):

No. due to the *distributed* nature of Git, you interact by pushing new commits from a local repo.
Even the latest [Octopress blog](http://octopress.org/) (using [rake command to create new post](http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/)) is base don the local clone, and a [deploy process to GitHub](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/).

Comment: While git is distributed, the wiki is a web application.  Certainly one can update the wiki using the web application without a local working directory (or touching git directly at all).  Github could choose to expose an API (and a library that interacts with it).  This is what I was hoping to find.

Comment: @cluesque But what GitHub does, when it allows you to edit, for instance, your `README.md` directly on the file, is to work with a working tree on their side (GitHub), and then pushing to their bare repo (still on their side). Maybe you can try and create a blob (http://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#create-a-blob), then create a tree (http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) and then create a commit (http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit)